# move both forward and backward in a script?

Tags: pine-script

I am new in pine scripting, so please excuse me if the question is easy or impossible.

Here is what I have in mind:

If possible, I want to write a pine script (in tradingview) such that for any GREEN candle (in time frame daily) computes two numbers:

number_1: the number of consecutive green candles after that.

number_2: the number of consecutive green candles before that.

Also for any GREEN candle,  I want to write number_1 above it and I want to write number_2 below it.

Thanks in Advance for you help and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int greenCount = na

if close > open and close[1] < open[1]
    greenCount := 1
else if close > open and close[1] > open[1]
    greenCount := greenCount[1] + 1

if close < open and close[1] > open[1] and greenCount[1] > 1
    for i = 2 to greenCount[1]
        label.new(x = bar_index - i, y = high[i], style = label.style_label_down, color = #00000000, textcolor = color.blue, text = tostring(i - 1))

if not na(greenCount) and greenCount > 1
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = low, style = label.style_label_up, color = #00000000, textcolor = color.green, text = tostring(greenCount - 1))
```